# How to get entity collection with connected entities from DB with pagination using Hibernate and Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For example, I have an Article entity, that has @ManyToMany collection of Rubric entities:

```
@Entity
public class Article {
...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "article_rubrics",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rubrics_id"))
    private Set<Rubric> rubrics;
...
```

Entity Rubric doesn't have reference of Article.
I need to get, for example, paginated collection of Articles:

```
PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdAt");
```

- If I will use `postRepository.findAll(page)` method, I will get N + 1 problem.
- If I will use HQL join fetch query `select p from Post p left join fetch p.rubrics where`, I Hibernate will take all posts & rubrics and paginate them in memory, warning: > HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory.

So what is the right way to get entities from DB? Maybe a way to paginate data in memory is not so bad?
Spring Boot 3, Java, Hibernate